# Apache Beam: How to emit a pane every hour

Tags: scala, streaming, apache-beam, windowing

I'm working on a Streaming Pipeline in Beam, and one of my PTransforms requires a Side input which needs to be refreshed every hour.

Despite reading the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing-basics), I am having trouble understanding if my approach is correct.
For context: The side input data comes from BigQuery, It should be `PCollection[String]`, which will later be aggregated into a `PCollectionView[Set[String]]`

So I am creating a `FixedWindow` of 1 hour with triggering of `AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()`

My concern is that I'm not sure what happens during the first hour the pipeline is executed at.

Here is the code applying the windowing and triggering strategy:

```
pipeline
  .apply(
    "ReadFromBQ",
    // elided
  )
  .apply(
    "ApplyWindow",
    Window
      .into[String](FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(1)))
      .triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane())
      .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(30))
  )
```

Supposing we have this *idealised* timeline:

```
00:00:00 -> Pipeline starts
00:00:00 -> 1st Window starts
00:01:00 -> First element arrives into pipeline and is placed into the window
00:01:05 -> Last element arrives into the pipeline and is placed into the window
00:59:59 -> Window closes
01:00:00 -> next window starts
```

Would the first pane be emitted at approximately 00:01:05 when the last element arrived or 00:59:59 when the window closes? Assume that the entire BQ result is very small and will be read into the pipeline in less than a few seconds.

If the first pane is emitted only after the window closes, would it mean that the transform requiring the input won't run until 1 hour has passed?